# Simple modules of a finite dimensional commutative $\mathbb{R}$-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, algebras

From Schur's Lemma, I know that simple modules of a finite dimensional commutative $\mathbb{C}$-algebra are one-dimensional over $\mathbb{C}$.  But what can we say about the dimension of the simple modules when they are over $\mathbb{R}$? I'd have to assume their dimensions would be $\leq 2$, but how would I show this?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Any ideas?

Comment: I've tried using Schur's Lemma somehow, but I can't seem to make it work because we won't always have an eigenvalue in $\mathbb{R}.$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple modules over a ring $A$ are just quotients of $A$ by maximal left ideals.  When $A$ is commutative, this means simple modules are just quotient rings of $A$ which are fields.

In particular, if $A$ is a finite-dimensional commutative algebra over a field $k$, every simple module is a field which is a finite extension of $k$.  For $k=\mathbb{R}$, the only such fields are $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$.  So any simple module over a finite-dimensional commutative $\mathbb{R}$-algebra has dimension $1$ or $2$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Why must a finite extension of $\mahtbb{R}$ be either $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Since $\mathbb{C}$ is an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{R}$, every algebraic extension of $\mathbb{R}$ embeds in $\mathbb{C}$.  So the only algebraic extensions of $\mathbb{R}$ are intermediate fields between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$.